# Rails.root filepath wildcards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, wildcard

Here's my code in a rake task to open a file:

```
  File.open(Rails.root.join("public/system/xmls/**/original/*.csv"),"r") do |file| 
  #etc
```

but it's not matching any file (there are three possible matches). The first ** is a folder with a 2 digit name. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `join` method doesn't usually expand `*` and `**` but puts them in as literals. Maybe this is the problem. What you want might be more like this:

```
Dir.glob(Rails.root.join("public/system/xmls/**/original/*.csv")).each do |path|
  File.open(path) do |file|
    # ...
  end
end
```

Open each file individually and you should be fine.

Comment: Comment by anonymous user (rejected edit): To iterate over each line, replace `File.open(path)` by `File.open(path).each`.